# Best practice for handling vector/matrix math?

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle vector-based properties in C#. I'm writing a program that performs coordinate system transformations in 3D space. Some of my objects' properties will be 3-element arrays (corresponding to X, Y, and Z axes) and others will be 3-by-3 matrices (XX, XY, XZ, YX, etc.).

I've narrowed it down to basically 3 options:

- Just use regular arrays (i.e. `double[3]`)
- Create custom classes with axis-based properties
- Use structs with axis-based properties

This is a new type of problem for me, so I wanted to reach out to the community to see what others have done in similar situations. What are the pros/cons to the approaches above? Are there any mechanisms already built into C# or the .NET framework to handle this kind of thing?

Comment: Best method is to use Matlab dll for doing matrix math and call Matlab from c#.

Comment: @fubo Thanks for the response. Can I ask why you'd recommend going with classes? And I assume you would create a class for vectors (X, Y, Z) and another for matrices (XX, XY, XZ, YZ, YY, YZ, ZX, ZY, ZZ) or would you somehow combine the two?

Comment: There are [standard types for vectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.numerics), with implementations focused on using CPU instructions optimized for that sort of thing (it's an active area of interest for .NET Core especially). Aside from that, there's a [host of libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries#.NET_Framework_languages_C#,_F#,_VB.NET_and_PowerShell). Most of these, too, focus on performance, as that tends to be a thing when you have vectors and matrices -- you usually have more than one, with a lot of operations on them.

Comment: @jdweng woah! I didn't know you could do that!! I'll have to dive into this. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Steve a Matrix could be `public class Point { public double X { get; set; } public double Y { get; set; } public double Z { get; set; } } public class Matrix { public Point P1 { get; set; } public Point P2 { get; set; } public Point P3 { get; set; } }` Matlab is also one option - depends on your requirements

Comment: You need the matlab Application Compiler which will create a dll.  Then use DllImport to call the matlab code from c#.

Comment: @jdweng So are you saying to essentially write the "math" part of my code in Matlab and use C# to create the interface between the user and the Matlab side of the program?

Comment: I've considered doing an application that has a similar problem for sometime.  I've never used matlab.  Without such external tools I would stay away from using `double` data types as your coordinate values, as they are an approximation of a real values.  Use `long` data types.  Then you can use a sorting algorithm to retrieve your coordinated objects, instead of being forced to look for approximated values.

Comment: @JimFell I'm afraid you lost me a bit at the end. When you say to use `long` data types, are you referring to using `decimal` over `double`?

Comment: @Steve You could use `decimal`, which is 128-bit.  I recommended `long` because it and `double` are both 64-bit.  It just depends on what the range of values you need to store is and how much memory is acceptable for your application to use.

Comment: @JimFell Is there a way to use `long` with non-integer data?

Comment: @Steve It's software, so there's always a way, but I wouldn't recommend it.  Trying to use a data type for storing something other than its intended type is going to add unnecessary complexity and overhead to your application.  You might look into boxing.  Basically it's where you can cast any type to `Object` and then later unbox it by casting the `Object` type back to its original type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191857/discussion-between-steve-and-jim-fell).